# Allow log in to the dashboard only from specific gadget?

Tags: login, dashboard

How can I allow log in to the admin dashboard WP from my specific tablet/notebook, and deny all log in from other gadgets?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a strong password and don't let anyone else know your password? the motivation for the question is not very clear...

Comment: I want to let a worker log in and work in the dashboard WP only from my device and only from my office. IP is not static.

Comment: The device always stays in the office.

Comment: if this is a device you use to login by yourself, than he can learn your password. In general if you do not have a trust in someone, you should just not let him do anything

Answer (score 0):

If you have static IP, simplest way would be to use the htaccess allow deny rules:

1. Find your IP (let's say its 1.1.1.1 for your tablet and
   10.10.10.10 for your PC)
2. Find the htaccess file in your WordPress installation (create one if
   it doesn't exist) and then add the following rule:

   ```
   <Files wp-login.php>
   order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   # whitelist tablet
   allow from 1.1.1.1
   # whitelist PC
   allow from 10.10.10.10
   </Files>
   ```

You can read more regarding the same here: [wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-limit-access-by-ip-to-your-wp-login-php-file-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But IP is not static.

Comment: If there was an IP range, you could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042399/htaccess-access-to-file-by-ip-range . If you could expand your question and add more details, maybe someone else could be of more help.